# Triage queue audit... I failed

Tags: discussion

The question was:

> Where can I find a reference document explaining the semantic of the Wigii xml configuration files ?

My action was `Looks OK` but I failed the audit with:

> This question is spam or nonsense and should be considered Unsalvageable.

I have never heard of it, but I did google Wigii, and it seemed legit. I am new to reviewing things, and want to do it right. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you share a link to the audit or the question?

Comment: Sorry no, Its gone now. But literally, that was the entire question not just a part of it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that was the entire question, then `Looks Good` is not appropriate -- that was a recommendation question, which is off-topic here.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try to factor that into my thought process.

Comment: Off-topic, yes.  "Spam or nonsense", I don't think so.

Comment: That the problem with this automated moderation. It is going to get things wrong. I am worried about it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This was the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855402/wigii-web-platform-xml-configuration-files-reference) (10k users) that triggered the failed audit. Image below:

[image]

Notice anything odd about the asker and answerer? This was flagged as spam because it was an attempt to seed links to a particular project on Stack Overflow. When the question was deleted, that flag was validated and the question became a potential audit case.

Without the context of the answer, it's not a great question, but isn't immediately obvious as promotion. As a result, I've cleared the spam flag on it and left the question deleted, which should remove it from circulation as a spam audit case.

Again, not something I'd mark as "Looks OK" in triage, but not a clear spam case either.

Comment: Nice to see I had the right idea how it got spam-flagged.

Comment: Why do you think it's "an attempt to seed links to a particular project"? The question won't get much views, because it doesn't use many key words and doesn't use any popular tags. The question is not good at all, but I don't see any misusage.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this in detail and providing including the answer for context. It makes much more sense now.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer in other news, most spammers are stupid in multiple ways.  It's a very weak question by two users with no other participation on the site which is suspicious in and of itself.  IF you goto wigii's site itself; both the asker and answerer are listed as contributors; which turns it into a slam dunk since a person who was involved in creating wigii obviously knows where the documentation exists.

Comment: @DanNeely: Self answering question is possible even on question creation, therefore as long as they don't promote their question by upvotes or something, I don't think it's spam.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer - The only purpose of this (badly asked) question was to give them a platform to post links to their project. This was not the only such question they did this on. That is considered excessive self-promotion. To their credit, they understood what they did wrong after we talked with them and won't be repeating this.

Answer (score 11):

You failed, because that question is unsalvagable:

We are not google, so asking for offsite-resources is off-topic.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Some speculation for the message you got there:

It probably also caught some SPAM-flags, because it was only posted to place SPAM-answers.
Or maybe the posters account was destroyed for spamming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it pointed me back to the `help-how to ask` which I will reference with an audit context so that I can do better next time.